# *ngFor com angular2

Tags: javascript, ionic, ionic2, angular

Gostaria de criar um laço de repetição, mas nesse laço eu já tenho a quantidade de vezes que ele vai executar. Segue abaixo um exemplo do resultado esperado usando javascript.

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log( i + 'estrelas!');
}
```

> No AngularJS 2, acredito que seria feito assim (é só um exemplo, já sei que não funciona mas procuro algo semelhante).

```
<ion-icon *ngFor="1 to 5" name="star"></ion-icon>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo apenas o padrão do Angular2 a syntax correta seria essa:

```
<div *ngFor="#hero of heroes">{{hero.fullName}}</div>
```

Onde ele apenas substitui a mesma função de `ng-repeat` do Angular 1.x, onde ele irá fazer o loop por toda a extensão de sua array, você não precisa nem especificar nem saber qual é a extensão dela. Se for 5, 10 ou 300 o `ngFor` irá passar por todas. A diferença entre o `ngFor` e o `for()` que você se refere, é que o `ngFor` é aplicado diretamente no template, ou seja, se você deseja fazer alguma manipulação dos dados antes de passar para a `view`, isso deve ser feito ainda no `component` responsável, ai sim você pode usar o `for()` para somente depois passar para sua view (html).

Tudo vai depender do seu objetivo.

---

#### Editado:

Confesso que nunca usei `Ionic`, mas se a lógica for a mesma que o uso de icon-font (o que imagino que seja) você pode usar um ng-class para aplicar a classe correspondente a quantidade de votos. Por exemplo:

```
<i [ngClass]="{
    'ion-android-star-outline': valorEstrela < 1, 
    'ion-android-star': valorEstrela >= 1}">
</i>
<i [ngClass]="{
    'ion-android-star-outline': valorEstrela < 2,
    'ion-android-star': valorEstrela >= 2}">
</i>
<i [ngClass]="{
    'ion-android-star-outline': valorEstrela < 3, 
    'ion-android-star': valorEstrela >= 3}">
</i>
<i [ngClass]="{
    'ion-android-star-outline': valorEstrela < 4, 
    'ion-android-star': valorEstrela >= 4}">
</i>
<i [ngClass]="{
    'ion-android-star-outline': valorEstrela < 5, 
    'ion-android-star': valorEstrela >= 5}">
</i>
```

Deste modo, você deve apenas atribuir o valor recebido do banco à propriedade `valorEstrela` e ela irá aplicar a classe correspondente ao preenchimento. De novo, como nunca usei `Ionic` não sei se existe uma opção melhor, mas acredito que essa que passei deva resolver seu problema de modo mais prático.

Comment: Meu objetivo é não trabalhar com vetor... É um esquema para rating, volta do banco um inteiro 4 por exemplo. Eu pego esse inteiro e tenho que printar 4 estrelas na tela.. Porém é um inteiro não um vetor.

Comment: Então não é o ngFor que irá usar, pois ele serve para interagir pelos objetos de uma array e exibir cada um deles na tela. Para atingir o seu objetivo seria necessário o uso de outra lógica.

Comment: Então @CelsomTrindade, eu sei que não é, usei ele apenas para expor minha necessidade..

Comment: É essa outra lógica que estou atrás, eu resolvi criando um vetor alocando a quantidade de posições necessárias oque é gambiarra =/

Comment: @HiagoSouza Você está usando o que para exibir essas estrelas? Icon font?

Comment: Estou usando a diretiva ion-icon

Comment: @HiagoSouza editei minha resposta, veja se é isso que você procura. =D

Comment: Desculpe a demora, apesar de não ter testado a maneira acima chega no resultado que eu esperava na época. Obrigado.